# MacBook M1 Pro slow Ethernet speed

Tags: network, ethernet

I have a Gigabit Ethernet adapter from Amazon Basics which for some reason, is giving me very slow Internet speed.   Changing the adapter with the same Ethernet cable increases speed back to 100 Mbps.

Amazon USB C Adapter Link: [AmazonBasics USB 3.1 Type-C to 3 Port USB Hub with Ethernet Adapter - White](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B01M8I8KMH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1)

Also, I tried manually configuring the speed, but it doesn't work and defaults to autoselected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "changing the adapter with the same ethernet cable"? It sounds like it's just a cheap adaptor that doesn't work very well.

Comment: If you’ve changed the adapter and you got the network throughput you’re expecting, you’ve already solved the issue:  it’s the adapter.

Comment: what's at the other end that is so fast? are you sure it's negotiating at full speed? Does your dud adaptor work to spec on a different machine?

Comment: I borrowed a USB 2.0 hub from a friend for testing and it got me 100 Mbps down. My Adapter gives me 10Mbps for some reason @benwiggy